# select2 - cannot display the placeholder with the numbers

Tags: jquery-select2

I use this sccript:

```
<select class = "form-control select2" placeholder data = "1" style = "width: 100%;">
```

I have a problem displaying a placeholder number.

Can someone help me. thanks

Comment: Paceholder is not an option for a select input field. The input shows a drop down. You can have a default by putting in a option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an default option

```
<select class = "form-control select2" style = "width: 100%;">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for responding,

Full script that I use is this:
(Displaying numbers 1-31)

```
<Select class = "form-control select2" placeholder data = "1" style = "width: 100%;">
<Option selected = "selected"> </ option>

<? Php for ($ i = 1; $ i <= 31; $ i ++) {?>
<Option> <? Php echo $ i?> </ Option>
<? Php}?>

</ Select>
```

when placeholder filled with string (eg: data-placeholder = "August"), was displayed. but not numeric (eg: a data-placeholder = "1")

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV4r9.jpg)

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9q61.jpg)